# In carrom, what if a player pocket the last piece of other player, while queen still on the board?

Tags: carrom

[image: same case that we have encountered and encircled black one is pocketed]
One player pocket the black piece of other player while the queen is still on the board.

Does the other player whose black piece was being pocketed by other player wins? If so, then by how many points?